# Weird numpy.sum behavior when adding zeros

Tags: python, numpy, sum, numerical-stability

I understand how mathematically-equivalent arithmentic operations can result in different results due to numerical errors (e.g. summing floats in different orders).

However, it surprises me that adding zeros to `sum` can change the result. I thought that this always holds for floats, no matter what: `x + 0. == x`.

Here's an example. I expected all the lines to be exactly zero. Can anybody please explain why this happens?

```
M = 4  # number of random values
Z = 4  # number of additional zeros
for i in range(20):
    a = np.random.rand(M)
    b = np.zeros(M+Z)
    b[:M] = a
    print a.sum() - b.sum()

-4.4408920985e-16
0.0
0.0
0.0
4.4408920985e-16
0.0
-4.4408920985e-16
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
2.22044604925e-16
0.0
4.4408920985e-16
4.4408920985e-16
0.0
```

It seems not to happen for smaller values of `M` and `Z`.

I also made sure `a.dtype==b.dtype`.

Here is one more example, which also demonstrates python's builtin `sum` behaves as expected:

```
a = np.array([0.1,      1.0/3,      1.0/7,      1.0/13, 1.0/23])
b = np.array([0.1, 0.0, 1.0/3, 0.0, 1.0/7, 0.0, 1.0/13, 1.0/23])
print a.sum() - b.sum()
=> -1.11022302463e-16
print sum(a) - sum(b)
=> 0.0
```

I'm using numpy V1.9.2.

Comment: I can reproduce with 1.9.2, but not with 1.6.1. My guess would be that the longer array somehow causes the elements to be added in a different order, for example in order to facilitate SMID.

Comment: With ``math.fsum()`` as well, which is different from ``sum()``, it seems not to happen (at least in 2.7.x).

Comment: I'd venture a guess that it's pairwise summation, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685

Comment: Cannot reproduce with python 2.7.6 and numpy 1.8.0

Comment: Also not  reproducible  on  python 2.7.5 and numpy 1.6.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer:** You are seeing the difference between

```
a + b + c + d
```

and

```
(a + b) + (c + d)
```

which because of floating point inaccuracies is not the same.

**Long answer:** Numpy implements pair-wise summation as an optimization of both speed (it allows for easier vectorization) and rounding error.

The numpy sum-implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src) (function `pairwise_sum_@TYPE@`). It essentially does the following:

1. If the length of the array is less than 8, a regular for-loop summation is  performed. This is why the strange result is not observed if `W < 4` in your case - the same for-loop summation will be used in both cases.
2. If the length is between 8 and 128, it accumulates the sums in 8 bins `r[0]-r[7]` then sums them by `((r[0] + r[1]) + (r[2] + r[3])) + ((r[4] + r[5]) + (r[6] + r[7]))`.
3. Otherwise, it recursively sums two halves of the array.

Therefore, in the first case you get `a.sum() = a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3]` and in the second case `b.sum() = (a[0] + a[1]) + (a[2] + a[3])` which leads to `a.sum() - b.sum() != 0`.