# numpy.sum() giving strange results on large arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I seem to have found a pitfall with using `.sum()` on `numpy` arrays but I'm unable to find an explanation. Essentially, if I try to sum a large array then I start getting nonsensical answers but this happens *silently* and I can't make sense of the output well enough to Google the cause.

For example, this works exactly as expected:

```
a = sum(xrange(2000)) 
print('a is {}'.format(a))

b = np.arange(2000).sum()
print('b is {}'.format(b))
```

Giving the same output for both:

```
a is 1999000
b is 1999000
```

However, this does not work:

```
c = sum(xrange(200000)) 
print('c is {}'.format(c))

d = np.arange(200000).sum()
print('d is {}'.format(d))
```

Giving the following output:

```
c is 19999900000
d is -1474936480
```

And on an even larger array, it's possible to get back a positive result. This is more insidious because I might not identify that something unusual was happening at all. For example this:

```
e = sum(xrange(100000000))
print('e is {}'.format(e))

f = np.arange(100000000).sum()
print('f is {}'.format(f))
```

Gives this:

```
e is 4999999950000000
f is 887459712
```

I *guessed* that this was to do with data types and indeed even using the python `float` seems to fix the problem:

```
e = sum(xrange(100000000))
print('e is {}'.format(e))

f = np.arange(100000000, dtype=float).sum()
print('f is {}'.format(f))
```

Giving:

```
e is 4999999950000000
f is 4.99999995e+15
```

I have no background in Comp. Sci. and found myself stuck (perhaps this is a dupe). Things I've tried:

1. `numpy` arrays have a fixed size. Nope; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525344/whats-the-maximum-size-of-a-numpy-array) seems to show I should hit a `MemoryError` first.
2. I might somehow have a 32-bit installation (probably not relevant); nope, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553549/do-i-have-numpy-32-bit-or-64-bit) and confirmed I have 64-bit.
3. Other examples of weird `sum` behaviour; nope (**?**) I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998305/weird-numpy-sum-behavior-when-adding-zeros) but I can't see how it applies.

Can someone please explain briefly what I'm missing and tell me what I need to read up on? Also, other than  remembering to define a `dtype` each time, is there a way to stop this happening or give a warning?

Possibly relevant:

Windows 7

`numpy` 1.11.3

Running out of Enthought Canopy on Python 2.7.9

Comment: probably because `numpy` integers rely on C-type integers, whereas python has unlimited integer range. floats are ... floats. They can be very high.

Comment: Check `np.arange(5).dtype`. It's probably using 32-bit integers instead of 64-bit. Also, make sure you're performing all these checks on the same Python installation.

Comment: Looks like some kind of overflow... the sign of the integer seems to be overwritten as well which is might be the reason you get negative results sometimes.

Comment: @user2357112 indeed it is printing `dtype('int32')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is clearly numpy's integer type overflowing 32-bits.  Normally you can configure numpy to fail in such situations using `np.seterr`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.seterr(over='raise')
{'divide': 'warn', 'invalid': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore'}
>>> np.int8(127) + np.int8(2)
FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in byte_scalars
```

However, `sum` is explicitly documented with the behaviour "**No error is raised on overflow**", so you might be out of luck here.  Using numpy is often a trade-off of performance for convenience!

You can however manually specify the dtype for the accumulator, like this:

```
>>> a = np.ones(129)
>>> a.sum(dtype=np.int8)  # will overflow
-127
>>> a.sum(dtype=np.int64)  # no overflow
129
```

Watch ticket [#593](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/593), because this is an open issue and it might be fixed by numpy devs sometime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for including the ticket. I suspected it was an overflow but the lack of any warning made me question what was really happening. That, combined with not knowing that Windows automatically converts int to 32-bit left me confused.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows (on 64-bit system too) the default integer NumPy uses if you convert from Python ints is 32-bit. On Linux and Mac it is 64-bit.

Specify a 64-bit integer and it will work:

```
d = np.arange(200000, dtype=np.int64).sum()
print('d is {}'.format(d))
```

Output:

```
c is 19999900000
d is 19999900000
```

While not most elegant, you can do some [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

np.arange = partial(np.arange, dtype=np.int64)
```

From now on `np.arange` works with 64-bit integers as default.

Comment: This makes sense to me but one of my key questions was whether there was a way to flag this. It's far too easy for this to fall under my radar when debugging; is there a way to identify that I missed this?

Comment: Added a possible solution.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine, the default is to use C long int, which Windows defined as a 32bit integer, even on a 64bit CPU.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a numpy expert, but can reproduce your `arange(200000)` result in pure Python:

```
>>> s = 0
>>> for i in range(200000):
...     s += i
...     s &= 0xffffffff
>>> s
2820030816
>>> s.bit_length()
32
>>> s - 2**32  # adjust for that "the sign bit" is set
-1474936480
```

In other words, the result you're seeing is what I expect if `numpy` is doing its arithmetic on signed 2's-complement 32-bit integers.

Since I'm not a `numpy` expert, I can't suggest a good approach to never getting surprised (I would have left this as a comment, but I couldn't show nicely formatted code then).

Comment: Start by searching for "two's complement".  With various fixed bit widths (8, 16, 32, 64), that's the scheme virtually all computer hardware uses to represent signed integers.  In a low-level language like `C` (which CPython and numpy are coded in), native hardware types like that are the ones you work with.  It takes a lot of code under the covers to implement Python's illusion of infinitely-wide two's complement integers.

Comment: Many thanks, I'm reading into it now. That "lot of code under the covers" has shielded me from a lot, thanks :) In this case, Wim has linked to an open ticket with `numpy` in his answer; it's been recognised that there is no overflow error in this particular case (which is what threw me) but it has been open for many years now :(

Answer (score 2):

Numpy's default integer type is the same as the C `long` type. Now, this isn't guaranteed to be 64-bits on a 64-bit platform. In fact, on Windows, `long` is *always* 32-bits.

As a result, the numpy sum is overflowing the value and looping back around.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is *no* way to change the default `dtype`. You'll have to specify it as `np.int64` every time.

You could try to create your own `arange`:

```
def arange(*args, **kw):
    return np.arange(dtype=np.int64, *args, **kw)
```

and then use that version instead of numpy's.

**EDIT:** **If you want to flag this**, you could just put something like this in the top of your code:

```
assert np.array(0).dtype.name != 'int32', 'This needs to be run with 64-bit integers!'
```