# "OverflowError: int too large to convert to int" in PyPy6.0.0 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.5, pypy

## Preface

There is a standard *Python* implementation known as [**CPython**](https://github.com/python/cpython). But it is not the only one, currently I'm working with alternative implementation named [**PyPy**](https://pypy.org).

## Problem

I have a strange inconsistency in behavior of *PyPy* & *CPython* implementations of *Python3.5* on *Windows 10 x64* with next snippet (thanks to @Gabriel, completed example)

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> repeat(None, 2**31)
```

in *CPython* it gives

```
repeat(None, 2147483648)
```

while in *PyPy* it ends up in error with odd message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: int too large to convert to int
```

but when I try to execute this snippet in *PyPy* inside of *Docker* container

```
docker run -it pypy:3-6
```

it works fine, as *CPython* version.

I know that *Windows* version is in beta stage, but can anyone explain why it behaves like this and what does this error message say (or what it should say)?

## Update

For *CPython* however next statement

```
>>> repeat(None, 2**63)
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

are these errors somehow related?

Comment: Just a guess, but I'm assuming this is due to a change with integers between 3.5 and 3.6

Comment: I guess windows has some crappy 32 bit build of itertools

Comment: My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705764/numpy-sum-giving-strange-results-on-large-arrays) is possibly related. Default integer type on Windows is 32 bit

Comment: that's probably because `2148000000 > 2**31`

Comment: @jhomr: nope, it's not, I have *Python3.5.3* for both implementations

Comment: What distro is your docker container using?

According to `http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#on-which-platforms-does-pypy-run` PyPy supports 64 bit Linux and Mac but only 32 bit Windows.