# I've discovered something strange

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

There is an error with Python.
Here is the code:

```
print(np.sum(np.power(range(26), 6)))
print(np.sum(np.power(range(26), 7)))
```

which gives the following results:

```
998881325
792709145
```

How can the sum of (x to the power of 6) < sum of (x to the power of 7) !?!

### EDIT

---

I'm on Python 3.7.3 and numpy 1.16.2.

Comment: I get 998881325 and 22267545625

Comment: "Now I have something new": please ask a new question. Now, the answer below only makes partial sense.

Comment: @00 done now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating integers that are larger than what your platform or default numpy int values can handle, so are *overflowing* your numbers.

25 to the seventh power requires 33 bits:

```
>>> (25 ** 7).bit_length()
33
```

Python's built-in integer type is *unbounded*, but numpy uses bounded, fixed size integers, and for your numpy setup, the default signed integer type is `int32`, so fails to fit this value.

I can reproduce the exact same output if I tell numpy to convert the output to `int32`:

```
>>> np.sum(np.power(range(26), 7)).astype(np.int32)
792709145
```

but because I have am running MacOS on a 64-bit CPU, numpy uses `int64` as the default integer type and so produces the correct result:

```
>>> np.sum(np.power(range(26), 7))
22267545625
>>> np.sum(np.power(range(26), 7)).dtype
dtype('int64')
```

`792709145` is the integer value represented by the bottom 31 bits:

```
>>> print(int(format(22267545625, 'b')[-31:], 2))
792709145
```

On Windows however, [the default numpy integer type is int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine) because even on 64-bit hardware Windows defines C long int as a 32-bit value.

You should tell numpy to create an array of int64 values here:

```
np.sum(np.power(np.arange(26, dtype=np.int64), 7))
```

Comment: I am running on 64-bit OS as well, so I don't know why this would happen by default?

Comment: The default integer type for numpy on Windows is 32-bit, regardless of the Python installation or OS both being 64-bit. I was bitten by this (and, sadly, continue to be every so often): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705764/numpy-sum-giving-strange-results-on-large-arrays. By the view count, I'm not alone :) @MRT

Comment: @roganjosh ah, indeed, i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine

Comment: @MRT: just a heads-up: as roganjosh pointed out, the default int type on numpy on Windows is `int32`, because that's what the Windows API says is the size of a C long int. This differs from other OSes on 64-bits architectures, where long int is 64 bits. I've updated my answer accordingly.